# Changing chunk options in the middle of a chunk

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm trying to print a plain-text table and an xtable in the same code chunk. The reason it has to be in one code chunk is that the tables are being run in a loop, and I need to keep the related tables together. Here is the code:

```
for(the.let in extra.out) {

    tmp <- readLines(paste("~/surveys/pathways-2017/tmeas/", params$themeas, "/table_32_2", the.let, sep=''))
    tmp <- gsub("^L", "", tmp, fixed=TRUE)
    cat(tmp, sep="\n")

   print(xtable(tab.13, caption=paste("Item Statistics in Measure Order for Run 2", the.let, sep='')),
          floating.environment="sidewaystable", comment=FALSE, include.rownames=FALSE)

    }
```

The issue is that the xtable needs `results="asis"` but if I use it for the table printed using `cat()`, the formatting gets all messed up. Is there any way I can turn on `results="asis"` only for the `xtable` part of the chunk?

TIA

Comment: Does this work? `knitr::opts_current$set(results =  "asis")`

Comment: Nope. I end up with the LaTeX source code unrendered in the document.

Comment: What do you mean with the output is all messed up ? Don't you need to add some space or new lines between `cat` and `xtable` so that it creates the table in a new paragraph ? You can add another `cat` section with a double space and a new line in it for instance.

Comment: No, @StatnMap, the problem is that with `results="asis"` the material I'm printing with `cat` comes out wrapped in a proportional typeface, instead of with correct formatting in a monospaced font.